# how to exclude a solution in 'solve' function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve an equation in MATLAB using 'solve' function. The equation is `f(x)=0`. `x=0` solves the equation (`f(0)=0`) but I don't want this solution (MATLAB always returns only this solution). I want any other solution (don't know if `x` is positive or negative). Is there a way to do that? I can't really use initial guess since I don't know anything about `x`. I just want to get anything that is not `x=0`.

```
syms t11 angle_x angle_y angle_z
eq4 = - (6032445600073213*t11*(...
       cos(angle_x)*sin(angle_z) + cos(angle_z)*sin(angle_x)*sin(angle_y)...
       ))/72057594037927936 ...
      - (10793*t11*(...
       cos(angle_x)*cos(angle_z) - sin(angle_x)*sin(angle_y)*sin(angle_z)...
       ))/100000 ...
      - (99063*t11*cos(angle_y)*sin(angle_x))/100000 ...
     == (2305710656601012*t11*sin(angle_y))/1939611812172049 - ...
      (656736840476999*t11*cos(angle_y)*cos(angle_z))/6537311985728952...
      + (904353052301071*t11*cos(angle_y)*sin(angle_z))/6982602523819376;
solve(eq4,t11)
```

Returns `0`.

Comment: Can you give some minimal working example code for us to play with?

Comment: sure. I uploaded the minimum code into this link:
https://github.com/David1324/problem_with_solve_function1

I want that $t11_solution$ will be a symbolic solution that is not zero (though zero is also a solution).

Comment: Try using [`assume`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html) maybe something like `assume(x ~= 0)`.

Comment: Looks like `t11` is a factor in each term

Comment: You're right. I had a mistake in my equation. t11=0 is indeed the only solution.
My mistake sorry.